# Is the REST API active in Italy for direct payment with credit card?

Tags: api, rest, paypal, payment

I just wanted to know if I can use the REST API to do a direct payment with credit card with an Italian account. I couldn't find any information about.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently REST API with the Credit card Payments is only available for US and UK merchants . You can check the link below for more information :

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/

So, Italian merchants can accept only the PayPal payments at this time.